# Google Sheet Summarize as Expand element

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I didn't know how to title this question.

I have this data from the Sales table:
[sales table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oy7jp.png)

And I have this Payments table:
[payment table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZcbS.png)

I wanted to create a pivot table so I could know the payments for each sale.Example:
[desired table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdgKI.png)

I was thinking about using query with pivot to do this. But I was unsuccessful.
In these examples, there may be more data for payment of an order. As well as more orders. I would like it to be automatic, when I insert the data from the sales table, and the payments table it goes to this new pivot table.(or if i remove some payment).

I tried using the query function, but I didn't find a way to "skip" to have blank rows. Or how to do it as payments can have several rows.

If anyone could help, I would be grateful.

Made a blank sheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NQ9vRnDjvNygj88kyulV1nDJbParmpErVzeZDZC8Rac/edit#gid=2100307022

Answer (score 0):

*[Here's one approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NQ9vRnDjvNygj88kyulV1nDJbParmpErVzeZDZC8Rac/edit#gid=1772389370) you may test out:*

```js
=reduce(tocol(,1),tocol(SALES!A3:A,1),lambda(a,c,ifna(vstack(a,join("    ",filter(SALES!A:E,SALES!A:A=c)),hstack(,filter(PAYMENT!A:F,PAYMENT!A:A=c)),))))
```

[image]